# Dynamic columns in e.g rich:datatable?

Tags: richfaces, seam, jsf-1.2

I have the following problem:
I use a a form with dynamic labels that each has a corresponding inputfield. This form can be sent multiple times. I want a table with a dynamic number of columns were each column has one label from the dynamic form as it's header. Now for each time the form is sent another row should be added with each input under it's corresponding header.

I've tried around some with the various components but have not been getting any useful results...

Basically what I have is one list with column headers and each element in that list has x values that should be listed under it.

I am using seam 2.2.2, richfaces 3.3.3 and jsf 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rich:columns](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_columns.html) does the job, but double read the notes in the documentation to avoid common pitfalls.

Comment: Any example of this? I just can't get it to work I have tried following that example a number of times

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic columns sounds pretty straightforward, you could set your input and a boolean if that input is set and then set the column to equal that input and render it with the boolean.  But you've lost me with the added rows, can you elaborate?

Comment: Using rich:columns creating the correct number of columns with headers that match the forms input labels is easy.

But the data to be represented under each column is stored in another List.

I try to hook that list up to the datatable but if I do that each value from the list gets printed under each column. But I want it to drop a value to every column until it runs out of values not write all of them to each column

Comment: Do you mean a column contains a nested table?  Can you post some code or a structure of what you're trying to create?